# Can we create instant android application for an existing application?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an existing Android application in google playstore. The size of the app is around 38MB. After much optimization and using remote resources and using Web image format, the APK has come down to around 25MB.

Inorder to create an Instant Android app, we need to breakdown our application into multiple modules and the common stuff goes into the base module. If i separate my app based on this basis i think each of my module will be less than 4MB. However, the complete bundle itself will be around 20MB+.

From what i have read `the instant app size must not exceed 4MB`. In my case the instant app is less than 4MB, but the overall bundle is huge.

My question is, in a scenario where the module sizes and instant app are less than 4 MB, but the entire Bundle size is 20MB+, Can we have instant app future to work on Play store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation

> For an app bundle to be instant-enabled, the combined download size of the code and resources within all instant-enabled modules must be at most 10 MB.

but

> When you use Google Play's internal test track, the Play Console doesn't apply the size limits discussed in the Google Play Instant overview. Therefore, you can test and internally showcase an instant experience, even if it's larger than 10 MB.

See https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/overview and https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle

https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/guides/reduce-module-size?tenant=irina could help you reduce your app size.

**Verdict:** If combined size of all the modules and resources are 20MB then looks like the only solution for you to make it work is reduce the size.